# A map between suspensions which is a homology isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

**Problem:** $Y \subset X$ be a subcomplex of a C. W. complex. Suppose that there is a retraction $r: X \to Y$.
Prove that there is a map from $\Sigma X \to \Sigma Y \vee \Sigma(X/Y)$ which is a homology isomorphism.

Taking the example of $X$ being the annulus and $Y$ the inner circle I get that the given spaces of suspensions are homotopy equivalent.

In general I think we need to show that $\Sigma X $ and $ \Sigma Y \vee \Sigma(X/Y)$ are homotopy equivalent. A homotopy equivalence, say $f$, will clearly give isomorphisms on all the homology groups.
But I do not know how to show the homotopy equivalence. In fact it is not necessary I think since the question only asks for homology isomorphisms.

Comment: Here is a hint: homotopy classes of maps $[\Sigma X, Z]$ form a group via the pinch map $\Sigma X \rightarrow \Sigma X \vee\Sigma X$. Use that to construct a map $\Sigma X \rightarrow \Sigma Y \vee\Sigma X/Y$ and use the axioms of a homology theory to show it induces isomorphisms in homology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin  Thank you. I now get it.  Briefly, the retraction gives split exact sequences and using the suspension functor we get the required isomorphisms on the homology groups. Tracing the maps and using that functoriality of the group structure you suggested gives that the isomorphism on the homology groups is induced from the naturally constructed map $\sum X \to \sum Y \vee \sum X/Y$.

Comment: Exactly! You should write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint from @ConnorMalin.

For any $X \in \mathcal{Top}_*$ $[\sum{X}, Z]$ has a natural group structure(denote by +) for any $Z$. The homology functors are linear wrt. to this group structure. $\cdots (1)$.

From the axioms of homology,
we have $\cdots \to H_n(Y) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X, Y) \to H_{n-1}(A) \to \cdots$.
Since $(X, Y)$ is a good pair we get
$\cdots \to \tilde{H}_n(Y) \to \tilde{H}_n(X) \to \tilde{H}_n(X/Y) \to \tilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \to \cdots$

$r : X \to Y$ being a retraction gives that the boundary maps are zero and the resulting short exact sequences split. We get,

$ \tilde{H}_n(X) \xrightarrow{[r^* q^*]^T} \tilde{H}_n(Y) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(X/Y)$.

Using another axiom for reduced homology that says $\tilde{H}_n$ is naturally isomorphic to $\tilde{H}_{n+1}\circ \sum$ we get

$ \tilde{H}_{n+1} (\sum X) \xrightarrow{[\sum r^* \sum q^*]^T} \tilde{H}_n(\sum Y) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(\sum X/Y)$.

Also, the inclusions $i_Y$ and $i_{X/Y}$ of $\sum X$ and $\sum Y$ respectively in $\sum X \vee \sum X/Y$ induce the isomorphism

$\tilde{H}_n(\sum Y) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(\sum X/Y) \xrightarrow{[i_Y^* i_{X/Y}^{*}]} \tilde{H}_n (\sum Y \vee \sum X/Y)$.

By $(1)$ the composition of the previous two isomorphisms is induced by $i_y \circ \sum r  + i_{X/Y} \circ \sum q$