# Constructing a map between suspensions that induces isomorphism on homology groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

This question is similar but different from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758292/a-map-between-suspensions-which-is-a-homology-isomorphism)
Let the spaces be locally compact, Hausdorff and based.

**Problem:** Construct a map $\Sigma (X \times Y) \to \Sigma X \vee \Sigma Y \vee \Sigma (X \wedge Y)$ which induces isomorphism on homology groups.

I think once again I must use the fact that $[\Sigma Z, W]_*$ has a group structure.

We do get the natural map,

$\Sigma (X \times Y) = \Sigma X \vee \Sigma Y \vee \Sigma (X \wedge Y)$ (where the first two  are induced by  projections and the last one by quotient)

and assuming $(X \times Y, X \vee Y)$ is a good pair and using $H_{k+1}\Sigma = H_{k} $ we get the following long exact sequence,

$\cdots \to H_{k+1}(X \times Y, X \vee Y ) \to H_{k}(X \vee Y) \to H_{k}(X \times Y) \to H_{k}(X \times Y, X \vee Y) \to H_{k-1}(X \vee Y)\to \cdots$

Now I want to have that the middle portion is split sicne that will give me $H_{k}(X \vee Y) \oplus H_{k}(X \times Y, X \wedge Y)  \cong H_{k}(X \times Y)$ but sice no other conditions are given I cannot conclude that.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: You should use the Kunneth theorem

Comment: @ConnorMalin, I think the final  Long exact sequence actually splits. Replacing $H_k(X \vee Y)$ with $H_k(X) \oplus H_k(Y) $ gives me a split injective map. Consider the $[\pi_1 ^* \pi_2 ^ k]^t $ from $H_k(X \times Y) $  to $H_k(X) \oplus H_k(Y) $.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, is the above correct?

Comment: I am not sure what your notation is meaning precisely. The LES does split. My recommendation was to just use Kunneth and replace $H_*(X \times Y )$ by $H_*(X) \otimes H_*(Y)$. Then the map $H_*(X \vee Y) =H_*(X) \oplus H_*(Y)\rightarrow H_*(X) \otimes H_Y(Y)$ is $(x,y) \rightarrow x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes y$.